# hide second dropdown untill first one not selected(Refreshing issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
hi i have two dropdown dynamic one . my question is when i load my chrome page/refresh the page all the dropdown value are visible without selecting first dropdown option value

 <script>

/* code for :select scheme, relative to department shown */

        $('#department').on('change', function () {  
         
            var departments = $('option:selected', this).attr('attr');
            $("#schemes option").each(function (i) {
                if ($(this).attr('subattr') == departments) {
                    $(this).css({ display: "block" });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css({ display: "none" });
                }
            });
        });
    </script> // this is the script for both the dropdown department is first dropdown id and schemes is second dropdown id //
```

note:
all the dynamic option are working well like when i select in first dropdown ,related to his values are shown    but when i refresh page and i select second dropdown all values are shown in dropdown without selected first dropdown and I am not excessing  according to selected option in both the dropdown when i refresh the page

thank you in advance
I am not able to get answer please help me

Comment: [**id must be unique**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: sir id will not be unique because in department dropdown i have 10 department and in schemes i get many schemes related to department   in each department i have almost 7 to 8 schemes

Comment: You must use [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)  attribute instead of `id`